# iOS Image Saving and Accessing Images From NSDocumentDirectory

Tags: ios

I am very frustrating about to accessing multiple images from NSDocumentDirectory. See the steps what i had done in this process and what i want to get from you.

My App can download images with the following code:

```
  // get the image from the url
  UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]];

  // Save the image file into document folder
  NSString *dir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];

  // Saving JPG File
   **NSString *jpefilepath = [dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dwallpaper.jpg",arc4random()]];**
  NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f)];
                                    [data1 writeToFile:jpefilepath atomically:YES];
```

With this code i download all images with unique name. and i use jpefilepath directly store in mysql database.

Now i have question about how to access images from directly local path with example code.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Load the image:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:jpefilepath];
```

Load the data:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:jpefilepath];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
    UIImage *testImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```